# How to check if the months in column is existing to the departments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

How can I check if the `current row` matches the `current column month and year`, if not match, set it to **0**.

So for example, this is the current data.

This is my **resultData**

https://pastebin.com/GHY2azzF

and I want to check if these data have this.

This is my **monthToCheck** variable

```
    "column": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "month": "Dec",
                "year": 2022
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "month": "Jan",
                "year": 2023
            }
        ]
```

This is the data from my backend, now after I received it to my front side, I'm trying to create a table wherein it will render the data and set to **0** if the ***month*** in that `department` is not existing.

This is my DataTable.

In this image, the data moves to the left because it is `blank`,

[image]

The `month or result` moves

This is another example to clarify the problem
[image]

This is how I tried to map it on front side.

```
const TableData = ({ totalUsers, loading }) => {
  let monthDates = Object.values(totalUsers)[1];
  let resultTable = Object.values(totalUsers)[0];
  const resultData = Object.entries(resultTable).map(([key, value]) => ({
    key,
    value,
  }));

  const monthToCheck = Object.values(totalUsers)[2]


  if (loading) {
    return <div>Data is loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHeader>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHead>Attendance </TableHead>
          {monthDates.map((item, index) => (
            <TableCell key={index}>{item}</TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCell>Total</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody>
        {resultData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>
                {item.key === "null" ? "NO COLLEGE" : item.key}
              </TableCell>
              {item.value.map((res, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell>{res.result}</TableCell>
                  )

              })}
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

Now like I said, how can I check the result if the `current row` matches the `current month and column` and then set it to **0**

The data should show like this. Thank you so much, I'm really sorry, my English is not that good.

What my Idea is, I'm trying to loop it but having a hard time on figuring it out.

I tried using find Method, but I'm having a little bit of trouble.

```
  const renderCell = (res, monthToCheck) => {
    const matchingMonth = res.find(item => item.month === monthToCheck.month && item.year === monthToCheck.year);
    return matchingMonth ? matchingMonth.result : ;
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Would it work if you transform the `resultData` to include the missing value and set the result to 0? You can then simply render the `resultData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to make sure having an array to store the header row for columns that contains the month and year you want. I hard-coded it in the script below, but you can dynamically extract the header from the original data.

```js
const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      key: "Department 1",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 4, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 19, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 2",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 36, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 28, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 3",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 8, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 50, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 4",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 1, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 34, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 5",
      value: [{ id: 1, month: "Jan", result: 11, year: 2023 }],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 6",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 2, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 21, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 7",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 17, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 72, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 8",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 38, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 14, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "Department 9",
      value: [
        { id: 1, month: "Dec", result: 44, year: 2022 },
        { id: 2, month: "Jan", result: 132, year: 2023 },
      ],
    },
  ];

  // The header columns
  const cols = [
    {
      month: "Dec",
      year: 2022,
    },
    {
      month: "Jan",
      year: 2023,
    },
  ];

  const renderCell = (arr, col) => {
    const row = arr.find((a) => a.month === col.month && a.year === col.year);
    if (!row) {
      return <td>N/A</td>;
    }
    return <td>{row.result}</td>;
  };

  return (
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        {cols.map((col) => (
          <td>{col.month} {col.year}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{d.key}</td>
          {cols.map((col) => renderCell(d.value, col))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```